# how to create a de-duplication engine that acts as a file storage, retrieval, and handling system?

Tags: data-structures

how to create a de-duplication engine that acts as a file storage, retrieval, and handling system. It must take some files as inputs, take data from it in chunks of 8 byte size and store it in some efficient data structure of our choice. The data structure should be robust and must not store duplicate chunks. Instead, it has to make a reference to the original chunk that is repeated.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking for. What are you trying to de-duplicate? Why would 8-byte chunks have anything to do with file de-duplication? Are you saying that the data structure should never store the same 8-byte chunk of data more than once? Seriously, the statements you make (I assume you consider them requirements?) don't give enough information to even attempt an answer other than, "huh?"

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the details.

1. How big are your chunks? Are the chunks 8 byte in size, or why is the 8byte size important?
2. How many *different* chunks do you expect, would a copy of all possible chunk variations fit into memory?

If all possible would *not* fit into memory, you could simply create hashcodes for each chunk and store them in a hashmap or tree, with a reference to a location to disk where the full chunk is found. Then if you look at a new chunk, you calculate the hascode. If the hashcode is not in the map, you got a new chunk which has not been seen before. If the hashcode matches an entry in the hashmap, you have to lookup the referenced chunk and compare the two chunk to see whether they are identical or not.

If the chunk *do*  fit into memory you can still use the hashmap approach, simply with buffering the unique chunks in memory instead of having to load them from disk. You could also you a critbit index. With a critbit index you could use the complete chunk as key, thus creating an ordered collection of chunks. The benefit would be that the critbit tree can use prefix-sharing, so it can store more chunks than would usually fit into memory; if to chink differ only in the last few bytes, it would store leading bytes only once for both chunks.